# Ubuntu 18.04 login endless loop

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I tried [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but that didn't seem to work.

When running `journalctl` I see the following errors. I can login with cinnamon but not with ubuntu

```
ago 28 21:14:16 system76-pc pulseaudio[1199]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provide
ago 28 21:14:00 system76-pc wpa_supplicant[878]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
ago 28 21:14:00 system76-pc wpa_supplicant[878]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: video: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: system76 system76: hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: system76: No NVIDIA device found
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: system76: Could not register NVIDIA audio device
ago 28 21:13:58 system76-pc kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b
```

`sudo cat ~/.xsession-errors`

```
monty@monty-Galago-Pro:~$ sudo cat ~/.xsession-errors
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:31:54 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ZE9OJLq9GX,guid=99ad602d50fedcdd0a6c7a435c45e5ea
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:35:05 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Nz7Sw1aHrL,guid=be005ed99badc82eafdc403e5c45e6a9
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:38:56 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-6gSBACXlUP,guid=8efabeafbe0b162eb049e8465c45e790
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:40:55 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Ep4OFzT2BI,guid=12daf8cdfe2fbd60fb4786ba5c45e807
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:41:40 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-zKV1GNP7cM,guid=34b7ccafcfa257b1b5743a665c45e835
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:45:46 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-YNhZZ11Fry,guid=fed0c64cd5d893c0ba603fb25c45e92a
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for root at lun ene 21 09:46:15 CST 2019
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-mqoc49nEVQ,guid=4934954ba2efbfc501c2c5f55c45e947
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/monty/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/monty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/monty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
```

Comment: Try turning off SECURE BOOT in your BIOS. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this too. I think it's an issue with GNOME 3.30.

Disable `workspace-grid`. It hasn't been updated for the new GNOME API.

`gnome-shell-extension-tool --disable-extension workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com`

https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid/issues/86